# Change z order of activity above dialog

Tags: android, android-framework

I work on customizing android ROM.I am changing the z-order of my activity to display above dialogs of type (TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG).

That means, when  dialog(TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG) is shown already and i get a broadcast intent to start another activity. This new activity should be displayed on top of that dialog. I swapped  the values of TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG and TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE in WindowManager.java. Now in oncreate of my activity i put

getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE);

but when i run i still dont see this new type. 
I then checked windowTypeToLayerLw() of PhoneWindowManager.java. There also i swapped values for these two flags. But its not working. Am i missing something?.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I replaced all system dialogs with normal dialogs, but maybe that's not the result you want.
I assume that you would like a specific activity to be run above system dialogs and not ALL activities (because otherwise you're in for some serious problems with Dialogs, PopupWindows etc. which won't be displayed at all).
Let's assume that you activity's package is named "com.package.com"
What I would do:

1) Don't replace `TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG` with `TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE`. Keep their original values.

2) In `WindowManagerGlobal.addView(View, params)` do the following:

a. If the current view that is added, is added with `params.type=TYPE_APPLICATION` continue   to b.

b. Check that `params.packageName=="com.package.com"` - if they are equal continue to c.

c. Assign: `params.type=TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`

One thin, though.. the Activity **MUST** run as a system process. Otherwise you won't be able to use any "special" windows (this is probably why your solution didn't work).

I haven't tested it, but this should work.